# Deleting [advice-request] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There is a tag [advice-request](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice-request), which in my opinion is useless, as:

- it is a meta-tag,
- in general, much content here is in fact an advice request,
- I have no idea how should it help.

Any pros or cons for deleting it?

Comment: Any tag that doesn't serve a useful and legitimate purpose should be recommended for deletion. I would propose that we use slightly higher standards than deleting or closing posts, since this affects site-wide activities: 7 or 10 net upvotes for a response that proposes deleting a tag should be sufficient to get the tag removed.

Comment: I agree with deleting it, it's a meta tag, and most questions on Academia.SE turn out to be a request for advice to some extent…

Comment: @aeismail Could you delete it? It seems that I'm not in power...

Comment: I think that the tags have to be deleted from the questions that have them. Then the tag is automatically deleted after reaching a "count" of zero. I did it for this one—but we should be sure not to have to delete a tag after it gets lots of "hits."

Comment: @aeismail You can upvote [this MSO request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124504/142977) for mass-untagging and tag deletion. It would be really useful to mods (yesterday, I wondered why you had flooded the home page, now I know)